# Openpyxl module: return weird value(not error) + hope to calculate

Tags: python, python-3.x, openpyxl

I wrote some codes trying to let the user be able to check the percentage of the money they spent(compared to the money they earned). Almost every step perform normally, until the final part.

a_c[('L'+row_t)].value  return:

> =<Cell 'Sheet1'.B5>/<Cell 'Sheet1'.J5>

yet I hope it should be some value.

Code:

```
        st_column = st_column_r.capitalize()
        row_s = str(a_c.max_row)
        row_t = str(a_c.max_row + 1)
        row = int(row_t)
        a_c[('J'+row_t)] = ('=SUM(I2,J'+row_s+')')  #總收入
        errorprevention = a_c[('J'+row_t)].value
        a_c[(st_column+row_t)] = ('=SUM('+(st_column+'2')+','+(st_column+row_s)+')')
        a_c['L'+row_t].number_format = FORMAT_PERCENTAGE_00
        if errorprevention != 0:
          a_c[('L'+row_t)] = ('='+str(a_c[(st_column+row_t)])+'/'+str(a_c[('J'+row_t)]))
          print('過往支出中，'+inputtype[st_column]+'類別佔總收入的比率為:'+a_c[('L'+row_t)].value)
```

Comment: What is the line **a_c[('L'+row_t)] = ('='+str(a_c[(st_column+row_t)])+'/'+str(a_c[('J'+row_t)]))** supposed to do?

Comment: a_c is the name of this sheet. Inside the bracket should be the cell, normally would be 'A4' or other string, but it could also be variance(control by user). User input st_column.r, which lead to the column(b, c, d, e, etc,) they want to put value in.

Comment: On the row 'row_t' of this sheet, I hope column L could calculate following equation: column 'st_column' divided by column J on the same row(row_t). Then return the value as excel normally do

Answer (score 0):

Try changing the formula creation to;

```
a_c[('L' + row_t)].value = '=' + a_c[(st_column + row_t)].coordinate + '/' + a_c[('J' + row_t)].coordinate
```

or use an f string

```
a_c[('L' + row_t)].value = f"={a_c[(st_column + row_t)].coordinate}/{a_c[('J' + row_t)].coordinate}"
```